# python-social-auth template url to jinja template url

Tags: django, jinja2, python-social-auth

How can i convert this django url tag

```
{% url "social:begin" "github" %}
```

to the proper jinja url tag? I have already tried

```
{% set myurl=url("social:begin", "github") %}
```

and then use the `{{url}}`

but i get an

> ImportError at /login/
>
> No module named github

My settings.py:

```
        UTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('social.backends.github.GithubOAuth2',)

        SOCIAL_AUTH_GITHUB_KEY = '75ba4983720f9852c22a'
        SOCIAL_AUTH_GITHUB_SECRET = '7e43083e9ee92bd95ad195064f3aaa91704cbfe0'

        INSTALLED_APPS = [
         'social.apps.django_app.default',
        ]
```

and my urls.py:

```
.....
i18n_urls = [
    url(r'^$', 'zerver.views.home'),
    url('social-auth/', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, you have to add `reverse()` to jinja enviroment as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2).

So, after that you can use in your template:

```
{{ url('social:begin', args=['github']) }}
```